# Upgrading from React Router v5 to v6, what is the syntax for the following code?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am making a search engine and want to route an array path to render Results component. The code for React Router v5 is this:

```
<Switch>
    <Route exact path={["/search", "/images", "/news", "/videos"]}>
        <Results />
    </Route>
</Switch>
```

What will be the v6 compatible syntax for this? I have tried the following, but it's not working:

```
<Routes>
    <Route path={["/search", "/images", "/news", "/videos"]} element={<Results />} />
</Routes>
```

I have imported Routes and Route `import { Routes, Route} from "react-router-dom";` of course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it supports arrays anymore and the regex that could be used is not supported anymore (see https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/upgrading/v5). The type definitions also says `path: string`. So you would need

```
<Route path="/search" element={<Results />} />
<Route path="/images" element={<Results />} />
<Route path="/news" element={<Results />} />
<Route path="/videos" element={<Results />} />
```

Comment: Didn't know about arrays not being supported in v6. This code becomes redundant but works.

Answer (score 0):

You can do as @bas answered or for a more easy approach and less typing, just do this.

```
{["/r1", "/r2", "/r3"].map((path, i) => (
    <Route path={path} key={i} element={<div>Same route</div>} />
))}
```

Here is an example:

https://codesandbox.io/s/happy-swartz-ikqdn?file=/src/App.js:2717-2846